# Class has no suitable copy constructor, do I need to initialize before passing to functions?

Tags: c++

I am encountering an issue when trying to pass an instance of my class to a function.
It reads "Class 'Workout' has no suitable copy constructor"

```
        while (choice < 4)
        {



            choice = menu();
            cout << endl;
            cout << endl;

            // Chooses menu option
            switch (choice)

            {

            case 1:
                displayData(workout, i);

                break;
            case 2:

                inputWorkout(workout, i);
                break;
            case 3:

                displayGoal(workout, i);
                break;
            case 4:

                //pushBinary(workout, i);
                break;
            default:
                return 0;

            }



        }
    }
```

This is how I am trying to use it, workout is my instance.

```
int choice;
    int athleteType;

    int personPushups;
    int personMile;
    int personSquats;
    string personName;

    Workout workout;
    Powerlift powerlift;
```

This is how I defined the class instance of workout.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string>
using namespace std;


class Workout
{
private:
    int pushups;
    int mile;
    string name;

    int gPushups;
    int gMile;

public:
    // Default constructor
    Workout()
    {
        pushups = 0;
        mile = 0;
        name = "";

        gPushups = 0;
        gMile = 0;
    }


    // Constructor
    Workout(int personPushups, int personMile)
    {
        pushups = personPushups;
        mile = personMile;
    }

    Workout(string personName)
    {
        name = personName;
    }

    Workout(int goalPushups, int goalMile)
    {
        gPushups = goalPushups;
        gMile = goalMile;
    }

    // Accessors
    int getPushups() const
    {
        return pushups;
    }

    int getMile() const
    {
        return mile;
    }

    int getGoalPushups() const
    {
        return gPushups;
    }

    int getGoalMile() const
    {
        return gMile;
    }


    void storeInfo(int personPushups, int personMile);
    void storeInfo(string personName);
    void displayInfo();
    void displayGoal();
    void saveGoal(int goalPushups, int goalMile);
};
```

And this is my .h file in which I defined the class.

I have never encountered this error before, is it due to the class definition or the way I use it in main?

thanks

Comment: [Can't reproduce.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/EP6cG9) Please create a [mre].

Answer (score -2):

you have to define `Workout(const Workout&)` in Workout class. This is called a copy constructor and it is used to make a direct copy of your instance.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-constructor-in-cpp/ refer to this page for more information about the topic

Comment: Ohh that is interesting, but now that broke my Workout workout; definition. Do i need to change the class definition? It solved one issue but created another.

Comment: now what is the error? Is there any text?

Comment: @Coderman after trying to reproduce the example, I noticed that you have both ```Workout(int personPushups, int personMile)``` and ```Workout(int goalPushups, int goalMile)```. This is the error. Both constructors use 2 int arguments, and that type of overload is not possible. You have to change one constructor so only one uses 2 int arguments.